# Control c3 chart overlay order

Tags: javascript, charts, c3

Is it possible to specify the which chart overlays on another chart?

In [this example](http://c3js.org/samples/chart_combination.html) the area chart is overlayed on top of the bar chart. I would like to have the area chart in my graph 'behind' the bar chart. For the data in my use case the area chart values will always be higher than the bar chart values.

Answer (score 3):

Change the order in 
types: { data3: 'spline',
         data4: 'line',
         data6: 'area',
} 
to
types:{ 
data6: 'area', 
data3: 'spline',
data4: 'line',
}

It is rendered in the order specified in

Comment: This no longer appears to be the case, the ordering in neither `data.types` nor `data.columns` appears to affect where the area is drawn.